# C# xml output from google search results

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I need a c# code to output xml results for google search results.

Please help!

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more? What service/API do you call? What do you get back? What do you want to do with it, and where are you running into a problem? This is a very unclear, very broad question.....

Comment: I am looking fro searching the http://www.uquery.com/
and results are set in a xml file in a specified format

Comment: Can you provide any code or more detailed description? Until that nobody can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Code" will depend on the XML returned and what you need to extract from that data equally "output" is a very vague term so you can't get a specific answer to the question as asked.

In C# there are various tools that you might apply address elements of this problem:

- Linq to XML will allow you to translate the XML into objects.
- In terms of display, you can bind XML to display elements in web, forms and WPF
- In terms of changing the format of the data you could look at XSLT which is specifically intended for manipulating XML documents into different formats (e.g. html)

But above all of this you need to break the problem down into manageable stages and identify and implement solutions to each stage - and in terms of Stackoverflow (just being a good programmer!) I think one should be looking for tools, patterns, approaches and methods rather than "code".

Answer (score 1):

It's not what you asked for, but you could use [Bing APIs](http://www.bing.com/developers).

TTBOMK Google dont offer similar APIs, hence anything else would be a third-party quasi-sanctioned approach.

Comment: Please refer here:

http://swik.net/XML/del.icio.us/tag/xml/XML+Output+for+Google+Search+Results/cgppz

Comment: i could make a count of the results using google search api 

but i need to make and xml file